# using a searched case in where condition

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I recently got this stored procedure where it is using a variable called @marketCode. The application is passing either South or null for this variable.

In my select statement, I want to retrieve every market except South if the application passes null.

```
and marketCode =! 'South'
```

If the application passes a non null value, then I will use that one instead.

```
and marketCode = 'North'
```

How can I join these two into one case?

```
 AND marketCode = (case @marketCode when null then <..not equal to 'South'..>
                                            else <..equal to 'South'..> end )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with an `OR` condition:

```
...
AND (
    (@marketCode IS NULL AND marketCode <> 'South')
  OR
    (@marketCode IS NOT NULL AND marketCode = @marketCode)
)
```